# Sending and processing an associative array from jquery to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a filter for some devices in a webpage, made of checkbox. Whenever one of the checkbox is clicked, i call a function which add to an object the value of the checkboxes checked. I want to send this object to a php file, via ajax, and use it to perform some MySQL query, then return the results from the php and display them on the page. The problem is, i'm missing something, since i kept getting a parseerror in my js.

Here's my code:
device-filter.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".ez-checkbox").click(function() {
    console.log("ok");
    var re = {Brand: "", Cost: "", OS: ""};
    $("#Brand :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        re.Brand += $(this).val()+" & ";
    });
    $("#Cost :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        re.Cost += $(this).val()+" & ";
    });
    $("#OS :checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        re.OS += $(this).val()+" & ";
    });
    if(re.lenght==0){

    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json", //type of data
            crossDomain: true,
            data: re,
            url:"./php/filtered-device-query.php",
            success: function(response) {
            //display the filtered devices  
            },
            error: function(request,error)
            {
                console.log(request+":"+error);
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

filtere-device-query.php

```
<?php
//connection to db
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "my_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { //verify connection
echo "Error to connect to DBMS: ".mysqli_connect_error(); //notify error
exit(); //do nothing else 
}
else {
//echo "Successful connection"; // connection ok
    $devices =json_decode($_POST['re']);
    echo var_dump($devices)."<br>"; 
    $myArray = array();//create an array
    $brand = rtrim($devices["Brand"], " &");
    $cost = rtrim($devices["Cost"], " &");
    $os = rtrim($devices["OS"], " &");

    $query = " SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `Brand` = '$brand' AND 'Cost' = '$cost' AND 'OS' = '$os' ";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);
    //if there are data available
    if($result->num_rows >0)
    {
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode($myArray);
    }

    //free result
    $result->close();

    //close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I'm not a JS guru (far from it), but I can tell when something is mispelled, and this being `lenght`. That should read as `length` for your `if(re.lenght==0)`. Edit: Along with what @Saty said about your column names. Checking for errors on that, would have helped you here.

Comment: Wrap of quotes from column name instead use backtick at `'Cost' = '$cost' AND 'OS' = '$os'`

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: possible duplicate of parse error and when to use single/double quotes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have some typos, first in the jQuery:

```
if(re.lenght==0){
```

should be:

```
if(re.length==0){// note the correct spelling of length
```

Then in your PHP you're using quotes on column names in the query. Those should be removed or better yet, back ticked:

```
$query = " SELECT * FROM `devices` WHERE `Brand` = '$brand' AND `Cost` = '$cost' AND `OS` = '$os' ";
```

**More importantly...**

An object, as you've described it, has no length. It will come back as `undefined`. In order to find the length you have to count the keys:

```
if(Object.keys(re).length == 0){...
```

The object `re`, as you've declared it, already has 3 keys, a length of 3. Checking for length of 0 is a waste of time.

---

[Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: I know, but those are unrelated problems. re.lenght is also wrong, and i have to delete it. And i know that the php is vulnerable, but first things first, i want my code to work, then to work properly. Still, thanks to pointing it out.

Comment: Unrelated problems? these are things keeping your code from working at all.